# Bin2c files won't generate on make

Tags: c, autoconf, automake, sdl-1.2, ps2

I'm trying to build SDL1.2 for the PS2DEV toolchain but the bin2c isn't generating the files I want from the Makefile. The files I'm trying to generate are freesd_irx.c sio2man_irx.c padman_irx.c mtapman_irx.c audsrv_irx.c ps2kbd_irx.c ps2mouse_irx.c ps2usbd_irx.c

Here's the relevent code

Makefile.in

```
ifeq ($(_EE), 1)
ifeq ($(USE_FREESD), 1)
../src/audio/ps2sdk/freesd_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/freesd.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ freesd_irx
endif

ifeq ($(USE_FREESIO2), 1)
../src/joystick/ps2sdk/sio2man_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/freesio2.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ sio2man_irx

../src/joystick/ps2sdk/padman_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/freepad.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ padman_irx

../src/joystick/ps2sdk/mtapman_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/freemtap.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ mtapman_irx
endif

../src/audio/ps2sdk/audsrv_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/audsrv.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ audsrv_irx

../src/video/ps2sdk/ps2kbd_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/ps2kbd.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ ps2kbd_irx

../src/video/ps2sdk/ps2mouse_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/ps2mouse.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ ps2mouse_irx

../src/video/ps2sdk/ps2usbd_irx.c: $(PS2SDK)/iop/irx/usbd.irx
    $(PS2SDK)/bin/bin2c $< $@ ps2usbd_irx
        
ifeq ($(ENABLE_MTAP), 1)
CPPFLAGS = ${CFLAGS}\
    -lpadx \
    -lmtap
else
CPPFLAGS = ${CFLAGS} \
    -lpad
endif

CPPFLAGS = \
    -lcdvd  \
    -lpatches       \
    -lkbd       \
    -lmouse     \
    -laudsrv    \
    -ljpeg    \
    -ldmakit    \
    -lgskit
endif
```

configure.ac

```
dnl Check if bin2c is installed
CheckBIN2C()
{
    case $host in
        mips64r5900el-ps2-elf)
            AC_PATH_PROG(BIN2C, bin2c, no)
            if test "$BIN2C" = no; then
                AC_MSG_ERROR([bin2c tool not found. Please install it or adjust your PATH.])
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            # Do nothing
            ;;
    esac
}

CheckPS2SDK()
{
    case $host in
        mips64r5900el-ps2-elf)
            _EE=1
            USE_FREESD=1
            USE_FREESIO2=1
            ENABLE_MTAP=1
            AS_IF([test "x$_EE" = "x1"],
                  [AC_DEFINE([_EE], [1], [Description for _EE])])
            AS_IF([test "x$USE_FREESD" = "x1"],
                  [AC_DEFINE([USE_FREESD], [1], [Description for USE_FREESD])])
            AS_IF([test "x$USE_FREESIO2" = "x1"],
                  [AC_DEFINE([USE_FREESIO2], [1], [Description for USE_FREESIO2])])
            AS_IF([test "x$ENABLE_MTAP" = "x1"],
                  [AC_DEFINE([ENABLE_MTAP], [1], [Description for ENABLE_MTAP])])
            ;;
        *)
            # Do nothing
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to build SDL1.2" Which SHA1?  "for the PS2DEV toolchain" Version and download location?  "the bin2c"  Is this in the toolchain download somewhere?  If so, where?  "isn't generating the files I want"  Why?  Build failure(s)  Missing makefile targets?  "the Makefile"  Which makefile?  "The files I'm trying to generate are <list of C file>"  Where are these located?

Comment: Sorry I had to update the question with the relevent parts of the Makefile.in and configure.ac.

Comment: Try `make clean`, followed by `make -j1 V=1` - the verbose output of make may contain enough clues as to **why** what you expect is not happening. `-j1` makes the output more intelligible, by avoiding mixing the output of simultaneous parallel jobs.